# how do I check my app url for itunes if my itunes apps' name has spaces?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes

If my app name is "abc : acb1234" on itunes, what would be my app's url?

I know "http://itunes.com/{appName}" would redirect to app's page on itunes but

I don't know what would be the url of appname if I have spaces between app names.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need app name, you need app id,
To navigate user to ur app in itunes just replace ur app id in the given below url

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=594105593&mt=8"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you add your app in iTunes connect?

If yes: iTunes Connect -> Manage Your Apps -> [Your app] -> View in App Store.

[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Dear you can get your application url from https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ . 
First login your account and click application summary there you find option view on appstore.